# Visual studio window arrangements

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, the default window layout seems to be as follows:

Visual studio window layout

[image]

The code window is on the left, the solution explorer and properties windows are docked on the right, and the toolbox is docked on the left. How can the positions of the code window, and the solution explorer and properties windows be swapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag solution explorer and properties windows to the desired location as illustrated here: [Customize window layouts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).